# Tracing is disabled in my QEMU. How to solve that?

Tags: linux, qemu, tracing

This was my configure command:
`./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-kvm --enable-trace-backends=simple --disable-werror` 
The build is also successful.
But when I'm doing: `sudo trace-cmd stat`, it  shows this:
[image]

```
Events:
 All disabled

Buffer size in kilobytes (per cpu):
   1408

Buffer total size in kilobytes:
   2816

Tracing is disabled
```

When I'm tracing a function, no trace file is being generated.